# Как получит три ответа по отдельности в pyTelgramBotApi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Ищу способ, как трижды спросить у пользователя дату
Вот код:

```
def change_check_times(message, user):
start_times = copy.deepcopy(_globals.CHECK_TIMES)
times = []

def inner(message):
    nonlocal times, start_times
    try:
        if message.text in _globals.CHECK_TIMES:
            _trash = time.strptime(message.text, '%H:%M')
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError: # if time not in CHECK_TIMES or time is not valid
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, _("Вводите только доступные даты", user.language))
        return bot.register_next_step_handler(message, inner)
    else:
        start_times.remove(message.text)
        times.append(message.text)

start = _globals.UNSUBSCIRBED_USER_CHECK_TIMES if not user.is_pro else _globals.SUBSCIRBED_USER_CHECK_TIMES 
for i in range(start, 0, -1):
    print(i)
    date_word = "дат" if i > 4 else "даты" if 1 < i <= 4 else "дату"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, _(f"Введите ещё {i} {date_word}", user.language), reply_markup=kbs(start_times))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, inner)
db.change_user(user.user_id, check_times=','.join(times))
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, _("Ваши времена проверки такие: " + ", ".join(times), user.language))
return start_bot
```

```
def kbs(buttons, one_time_keyboard=True):
    kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=one_time_keyboard, row_width=len(buttons)//2)
    kb.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(i) for i in buttons])
    return kb
```

```
_(smth) - перевод текста
user - класс пользователя
```

Я хочу спросить первый раз, подождать ответа, второй раз, подождать ответа, и тд

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Решил вопрос сам, решение получилось более простым в использовании, более универсальным
Вот решение:

```
def change_check_times(message, user):
    available_times = copy.deepcopy(_globals.CHECK_TIMES)
    chosen_times = []
    start = _globals.UNSUBSCIRBED_USER_CHECK_TIMES if not user.is_pro else _globals.SUBSCIRBED_USER_CHECK_TIMES

    def inner(message, iteration_num):
        nonlocal chosen_times, available_times
        try:
            if message.text in _globals.CHECK_TIMES:
                time.strptime(message.text, '%H:%M')
                iteration_num -= 1
                available_times.remove(message.text)
                chosen_times.append(message.text)
            else:
                raise ValueError

            if iteration_num == 0:
                db.change_user(user.user_id, check_times=','.join(chosen_times))
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, _("Ваши времена проверки такие: " + ", ".join(chosen_times), user.language))
                return start_bot(message)
        except ValueError: # if time not in CHECK_TIMES or time is not valid
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, _("Вводите только доступные даты", user.language))
            return bot.register_next_step_handler(message, inner, iteration_num)
        else:
            date_word = "дат" if iteration_num > 4 else "даты" if 1 < iteration_num <= 4 else "дату"
            bot.send_message(
                message.chat.id,
                _(
                    f"Введите ещё {iteration_num} {date_word}",
                    user.language),
                reply_markup=kbs(available_times)
            )
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, inner, iteration_num)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        _(
            f'Выберите {start} {"дат" if start > 4 else "даты" if 1 < start <= 4 else "дату"}',
            user.language
        ),
        reply_markup=kbs(available_times))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, inner, start)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите первое значение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите второе значение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_3, message.text)


def start_3(message, value):
    print(message.text, value)
```