# Как работает метод register_next_step_handler в pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telebot

Пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой telebot. не могу разобраться как в этом методе происходит ожидание ввода данных от пользователя?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## register_next_step_handler()

Принимает два обязательных аргументы первый это `message`, а второй это `function`.
Работает таким образом, он ждёт сообщение пользователя и потом вызывает указанную функцию
с аргументом `message`
Пример использования:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Please send me message')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg,test)


def test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'You send me message')
```

**Если возникли вопросы, задавайте их смело в комментариях.**

Comment: А как происходит ожидание? Функция в функции?

Comment: Ожидание происходит таким образом, пока аргумент `message` пустой он ждёт.
Как только он стал не пустым он визивает в нашем случае `test(mesg)` . Я вам помог?

Comment: Все стало на свои места. Спасибо за помощь )

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216725/234134 так же можно передавать аргументы в "следующую" функцию

Comment: а как убрать это ожидание если ответ от пользователя уже не нужен?