# Не вызывается функция и telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, асинхронность

```
bots = Bot(token = tokens)
dp = Dispatcher(bots)

def subscriber_input(message: types.Message):
    #....

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_inline(callback):
    try:
        if callback.message:
            if callback.data=="another":
                mess = bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Напишите количество подписчиков?")
                bot.register_next_step_handler(mess, subscriber_input) # не вызывается
```

Бот присылает сообщение:
Напишите количество подписчиков?

Пользователь: (к примеру) 10

Это сообщение должно передаться в функцию subscriber_input

Но функция subscriber_input не вызывается и при этом нет никакой ошибки, просто ничего не происходит );

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1243528

Comment: @4500zenja не помогло( , щас переделаю и покажу как я сделал

Comment: *Я добавил переменную mess

Comment: Может ли это быть проблемма в Dispatcher? (dp)

Comment: Я думаю проблема в том что в aiogram'e отсутствует функция register_next_step_handler

Comment: @oleksandrigo да, и в правду. Шпасибо)