# Бот пропускает проверку сообщения

Tags: python, telebot

бот пропускает блок if и сразу же переходит к блоку else. Как заставить бота сделать проверку на if?

```
elif message.text == "4️⃣":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Запиши номер строки/строк с правильным ответом.\nНапример: 35 ")
    
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,
photo=open('/home/rslv/PycharmProjects/pythonProject30/photo/4.png', 'rb'))

    if message.text == "14":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Правильно✅")
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Неправильно. Попробуй еще раз.")
```

код начиная с декоратора:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == "Старт":
        markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        markup.add("4️⃣")
        markup.add("5️⃣")
        markup.add("7️⃣")
        markup.add("9️⃣")
        markup.add("")
        markup.add("1️⃣1️⃣")
        markup.add("1️⃣2️⃣")
        markup.add("1️⃣2️⃣")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         text="Выбери, какое задание будем решать? Все задания соответствуют демоверсии 2023 года.\n\n 4 - постановка ударения \n\n 5 - паронимы \n\n 7 - числительные, формы прилагательного, существительные \n\n 9 - правописание корней"
                              "\n\n 10 - правописание приставок \n\n 11 - Правописание суффиксов существительных, "
                              "прилагательных, наречий, глаголов, причасти \n\n 12 - Правописание суффиксов глаголов и "
                              "причастий(зависимость от спряжения глаголов)", reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == "4️⃣":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                            text="Запиши номер строки/строк с правильным ответом. \nНапример: 35 ")
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,
                       photo=open('/home/rslv/PycharmProjects/pythonProject30/photo/4.png', 'rb'))
```

Comment: A посмотрите, что у вас в print(message.text)

Comment: Дайте код начиная с декоратора

Comment: После срабатывания условия `message.text == "4️⃣"` не стоит ждать, что `message.text == "14"` вдруг выполнится, ведь в переменной `4️⃣` . Примечание: после того, как вы отправляете новый вопрос, `message` остается без изменений, то есть продолжает хранить `4️⃣`, а не ответ пользователя. Вам нужно несколько функций-обработчиков. Поможет [это](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html?highlight=register_next_step_handler#telebot.TeleBot.register_next_step_handler) / [то же, но по русски](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243534/384202)

Comment: загрузил код начиная с декоратора