# Сохранить данные, введённые пользователем через клавиатуру telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Мой бот отправляет пользователю картинку и две кнопки, пользователь нажимает на одну из них. Не могу понять, как запомнить выбор пользователя и записать его в базу, вместе с названием выбранной картинки?

Алгоритм бота: отослал фото -> пользователь нажал на одну из кнопок (оценку фото) -> записана оценка фото и наименования

Comment: Привет! На этом форуме принято прикладывать код, чтобы другим людям было легче понять, в чем ваша проблема. Я думаю, что вы используете `telebot`, поэтому смотрите в сторону `bot.register_next_step_handler()`. Если вы приложите часть кода, то я, наверно, смогу помочь больше.

Comment: Вы можете исправить свой вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: Приветствую, извините, но код сейчас не могу приложить... Но вот что добавлю, насколько я понимаю, метод, о котором вы говорить мне не поможет, т.к.  он вызывает функцию-обработчик и присылает в нее аргументом сообщение пользователя, т.е. ответ, в моем случае одна из двух кнопок...

Comment: Да, Я использую телебот

Comment: А мне же нужно как-то зарегистрировать, что пользователь нажал одну из двух кнопок именно к этой фотографии, просто у меня видимо какая-то проблема с логикой...

Comment: Если я неправильно понял вас, пожалуйста, объясните на примере бот отослал фото -> пользователь нажал на одну из кнопок (оценку фото) -> записана оценка фото и наименования фото

Comment: Вы используете inline кнопки?

Comment: Нет, Я использую кнопки в клавиатуре, ну типо как меню, там где обычно кнопка старт у всех ботов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, если вы хотите сохранить результат пользователя, не используя callback, то вам придется использовать `bot.register_next_step_handler()`

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужен функционал такого рода (словарь `data`, само собой нужно заменить базой данных)

```
def photo_kb():
    kb_photo = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, row_width=5)
    star_1 = types.KeyboardButton("1")
    star_2 = types.KeyboardButton("2")
    star_3 = types.KeyboardButton("3")
    star_4 = types.KeyboardButton("4")
    star_5 = types.KeyboardButton("5")
    kb_photo.add(star_1, star_2, star_3, star_4, star_5)
    return kb_photo


data = {
    "photo": "",
    "stars": 0
}


@bot.message_handler(
    func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == "фото")
def photo_send(message):
    image_file = random.choice(["img/1.png", "img/2.png"])
    img = open(image_file, 'rb')
    data["photo"] = img.name
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Оцени", reply_markup=photo_kb())
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, set_star)


def set_star(message):
    data['stars'] = int(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Спасибо!")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{data["photo"]} {data["stars"]}')
```

Comment: Вот тут простыми словами описана логика работы функции: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-register-next-step-handler-%D0%B2-pytelegrambotapi

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!!!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь :)