# register_next_step_handler в условии

Tags: python, telebot

почему register_next_step_handler не работает в условии?

(если что это только часть кода)

```py
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup ()
    agreeButton = types.KeyboardButton ("Хорошо, я не буду отключать уведомления.")
    markup.row (agreeButton)

    #сообщение перед кнопкой
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}! Я создан, чтобы помогать тебе! Я буду напоминать тебе спрашивать твоего партнера как он и присылать ему комплименты. \n\nПожалуйста, <b>не отключайте уведомления</b> от меня! Чтобы я мог присылать вам вопросы и комплименты.", reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="html")

    if message == "Хорошо, я не буду отключать уведомления.":
        bot.register_next_step_handler (message, choice_button)

def choice_button (message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    yes_button = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
    no_button = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")
    markup.row(yes_button, no_button)

    #сообщение перед кнопкой
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, "Я имею базовые вопросы: \nКак дела? Что делаешь? \nКак спалось? Что снилось? \n\nНо вы можете добавить до пяти своих вопросов. Добавить?", reply_markup = markup)

    bot.register_next_step_handler (message, first_question)
```

[image: после "Хорошо, я не буду отключать уведомления." ничего не происходит]

Comment: Мне интересно как ваш код вообще запускается? Скорее всего вы вырвали прямо из кода частями, в следующий раз не надо так.

Comment: И я уже отвечал на ваш вопрос с аналогичным содержанием.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут можно почитать про ваш вопрос: [Как работает метод register_next_step_handler в pyTelegramBotAPI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-register-next-step-handler-%D0%B2-pytelegrambotapi)

```
@bot.message_handler()
def mes(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    agree_button = types.KeyboardButton("Хорошо, я не буду отключать уведомления.")
    markup.row(agree_button)
    for_next_step = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                     f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}! Я создан, чтобы помогать тебе! Я буду "
                                     f"напоминать тебе"
                                     f"спрашивать твоего партнера как он и присылать ему комплименты. \n\nПожалуйста, "
                                     f"<b>не отключайте уведомления</b> от меня! Чтобы я мог присылать вам вопросы и "
                                     f"комплименты.",
                                     reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="html")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(for_next_step, choice_button)


def choice_button(message):
    if message.text == "Хорошо, я не буду отключать уведомления.":
        markup_second = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        yes_button = types.KeyboardButton("Да")
        no_button = types.KeyboardButton("Нет")
        markup_second.row(yes_button, no_button)

        for_next_step = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                         "Я имею базовые вопросы: \nКак дела? Что делаешь? \nКак спалось? Что снилось? \n\nНо вы можете добавить до пяти своих вопросов. Добавить?",
                                         reply_markup=markup_second)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(for_next_step, first_question)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка")
```

Comment: Хочу еще добавить по вашим ошибкам, не относящимся к вопросу. 1. Не `camelCase`, а `snake_case` 2. Невозможно использовать `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ...)` без функции с аргументом `message` 3. `if message ...` не дал бы нужного результата, а дал бы вам объект с огромным количеством данных, не только сообщение, поэтому стоило использовать `message.text`