# как сделать кнопку 'Оставить Заявку" в телеграм боте библеотке telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Помогите пожалуйста сделать кнопку 'Оставить Заявку"  в телеграм боте библиотека telebot. Что бы мне приходила
текст заявки и от кого было отправлена заявка

Comment: `Помогите пожалуйста сделать...`. StackOverflow - не фриланс биржа. Здесь не напишут готовый код за вас. Но мы можем разобрать конкретные проблемы/ошибки, которые могут возникнуть.

Comment: `btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Оставить заявку', callback_data='call_name')` не благодарите. Вы же просили кнопку

Comment: @mironovmeow спасибо теперь буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не люблю вопросы такого формата, но решение под руку попало.
Поиграю в Вангу, что примерно у вас не получилось.
Думаю, `bot.register_next_step_handler()` про это есть нескончаемое множество вопросов, вот тут лучший, по моему мнению: [Как работает метод register_next_step_handler в pyTelegramBotAPI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243528/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-register-next-step-handler-%D0%B2-pytelegrambotapi)

Про кнопку вам уже в комментариях подсказали

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda
        message: message.text.lower() == "оставить отзыв ✨" or message.text.lower() == "оставить отзыв" or message.text.lower() == "отзыв")
def send_review(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                            "Здесь ты можешь оставить отзыв")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, from_review)
def from_review(message):
    bot.send_message(ВАШ TG ID (не юзернейм),
                     f" Отзыв от {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}\n\n{message.text}\n\n▶ @{message.from_user.username}")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отзыв отправлен, спасибо ✨")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @kikles Если вам помог мой ответ, нажмите на зеленую галочку слева, это будет означать, что мой ответ верный