# Последовательная цепочка в Telegram Bot Api на php

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем, доброго времени суток! Стоит такая цель:

1. Команда /new отправляет пользователю текст "Введите номер заявки"
2. Пользователь должен ввести номер заявка
3. Бот отправляет сообщение "Введите комментарий к заявке"
4. Пользователь отправляет боту комментарий
5. Бот отправляет сообщение "Отправьте фотографию"
6. Пользователь отправляет фотографию

Затем все входные данные пользователя должны сохраниться в базу данных.

Я использую Laravel с пакетом  irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Пробовал через команды реализовать, но я должен передать аргумент когда пишу команду "/new 156" например, данный вариант не подходит. Через условия в вебхуке не совсем допираю как сохранять все входные параметры.

Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться и если есть возможность примерный код.

Я искал как ожидать ввода пользователя в командах но так ничего и не нашел.

Comment: Думаю чтото должно быть в телеграм апи, но раз не можешь разобраться то сейви временно в бд

Comment: пример на Python https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216725/234134

Comment: @Flecso для таких целей придумали сессии, а в качестве провайдера сессий можно использовать `Redis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Пользователь пишет боту /new XXXXX
2. В сообщении, которое прилетело в вебхук выбираешь текст и удаляешь из него '/new ', самое простое - `$order = str_replace('/new ', '', $input)`
3. $order - номер заявки. Сохраняешь в базу/Redis номер заявки и telegram_id пользователя (тоже берешь из входных данных)
4. Ну дальше у тебя есть ID пользователя в телеграмме и номер заявки. Можешь через условия проверять что пользователь пишет, находить его в базе и смотреть его заявку

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача легко решается через пакет [BotMan studio](https://botman.io/2.0/welcome).