# Запрос ввода сообщения после нажатия кнопки TelegramBot Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Натыкался на похожие темы на форуме, но ни одна не дала ясный ответ(
Пользователю выдается несколько кнопок: Ввести текст, ввести изображение, завершить. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ввода текста, бот ожидал текст от пользователя после чего должны быть выведены кнопки "Назад", которая возвращает в "главное меню", где пользователь может заново выбрать вввод текста либо картинки и "Завершить".

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'post':
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить/Изменить текст.', callback_data='tex')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить/Изменить пикчу.', callback_data='pik')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Завершить.', callback_data='end')
        mainmenu.add(item1, item2, item3)
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=mainmenu)
    elif call.data == 'tex':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жду текст.')
        #ввод текста
        nextmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад.', callback_data='post')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Завершить.', callback_data='end')
        nextmenu.add(item4, item5)
        bot.edit_message_text('Выбери дальнейшее действие.',call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=nextmenu)
    elif call.data == 'pik':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жду пикчу.')
        #Ввод картинки
        nextmenu2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад.', callback_data='post')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Завершить.', callback_data='end')
        nextmenu2.add(item6, item7)
        bot.edit_message_text('Выбери дальнейшее действие.', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=nextmenu2)
    elif call.data == 'end':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ваше сообщение принято')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните что означает "обрабатывался вввод".

Comment: @Kamanaftius, register next step handler - гугли. Или меня библиотеку на aiogram

Comment: @Никита значит, чтобы пользователь мог ввести данные (конкретно текст либо картинку).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216725/234134